# Inexplicable slow MySQL join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty simple query that gives me headaches because of a very long execution time which I cannot explain. The query:

```
explain select A.* from NAV_ADRESSEN A left outer join MITGL_KENNZEICHEN K on (K.MNR=A.MNR)
where ((A.MNR='19012546') or (IMPORTID='19012546') or (K.KENNZEICHEN='19012546')) and 
(not UNGUELTIG) order by ZUNAME, VORNAME limit 0, 25;
```

The query (the real one, not the `explain`) takes about 17 seconds, whether or not any matches are found.

The explain result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref             rows Extra
1   SIMPLE      A       index   MNR,IMPORTID    ZUNAME  164     NULL            25   Using where
1   SIMPLE      K       ref     MNR             MNR     23      gsco-test.A.MNR 1    Using where
```

This looks pretty normal to me. All relevant columns have keys (A.MNR, K.MNR, A.IMPORTID, K.KENNZEICHEN); the tables contain ~600 000 rows (NAV_ADRESSEN) and 180 rows (MITGL_KENNZEICHEN).

What could be the problem?

*Edited to add:*

The explain looks slightly different when leaving out the `limit` clause (but the execution time doubles):

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key   key_len  ref              rows    Extra                        
1   SIMPLE       A      ALL   MNR,IMPORTID   NULL  NULL     NULL             544587  Using where; Using filesort  
1   SIMPLE       K      ref   MNR            MNR   23       gsco-test.A.MNR  1       Using where
```

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `MITGL_KENNZEICHEN` (
  `PK` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MNR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KENNZEICHEN` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),
  KEY `MNR` (`MNR`),
  KEY `KENNZEICHEN` (`KENNZEICHEN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=247 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

... and ...

```
CREATE TABLE `NAV_ADRESSEN` (
  `PK` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MNR` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
-- ... 50 fields omitted for brevity ...
  `UNGUELTIG` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IMPORTID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MATCHCODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MNR` (`MNR`),
  KEY `ZUNAME` (`ZUNAME`,`VORNAME`),
  KEY `IMPORTID` (`IMPORTID`),
  KEY `MATCHCODE` (`MATCHCODE`),
  KEY `ANGELEGTDAT` (`ANGELEGTDAT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1076829 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: PLease addd the ddl of both tables.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to see the EXPLAIN without the LIMIT

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, that query can (presumably) be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM nav_adressen a
  JOIN mitgl_kennzeichen k
    ON k.mnr = a.mnr
   AND 19012546 IN (a.mnr,importid,k.kennzeichen)
   AND NOT ungueltid 
 ORDER 
    BY zuname
     , vorname 
 LIMIT 0,25;
```

Comment: Interesting, when I rewrite it like this, the execution time goes down to 7 ms - so effectively it solves the problem. But why?

Comment: Dunno, caching? Please provide the EXPLAIN and proper DDLs. Although LEFT JOIN with OR (when OR refers to both LEFT and RIGHT tables) might be a factor - I always avoid that one because I don't really understand the logic of that kind of statement.

Comment: Index is used when query is written like this, opposed to not being used and forcing full table scan - that's why. +1 for the proper query.

Comment: N.B.: Why/where does it use a full table scan? The `explain` says it uses an index...

Comment: OK, some more results: replacing the `where` with `and` (thereby making all criteria part of the join criteria) makes the difference, not the `in` syntax.

Comment: I wonder if it helps to 1. add an index on `ungueltig` and 2. remove the separate indexes on `k.mnr` and `k.kennzeichen` and instead provide those as a compound index?